# Memory exception scanning with mmscomputing

Tags: java, twain

I've tried to set the scan resolution with TwainAppletExample.java (update method) and its throwing this:

> uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainFailureException: Failed during
>   call to twain source. cc=Not enough memory to perform operation

i know about a fixed memory [bug](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/news/index.html) in 2009-04-23, but i just found an old version [here](http://aigleon.blogspot.com/2011/03/no-se-si-alguien-encuentre-esto-asi-que.html)
  (last update in 2008-07-25) so maybe it's a version problem.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: After trying i got the last sources from [link](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/) , hope its usefull